# issue after migrate from jss-to-styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Migrate it from JSS to styled

`npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/jss-to-styled ./`

by using this command code migrate is done successfully but after migration, my classes are not working make styles is changed in styled whatever class name that I am using from makeStyle after migrating that not working no classes are applied no error is shown but CSS class is not applied let me know if I am missing something that I need to change after JSS to styled migrate.

```
const PREFIX = 'InitialScreening';

const classes = {
  root: `${PREFIX}-root`,
  formControl: `${PREFIX}-formControl`,
  paper: `${PREFIX}-paper`,
  card: `${PREFIX}-card`,
  textCapitalize: `${PREFIX}-textCapitalize`,
  searchTextfield: `${PREFIX}-searchTextfield`
};

const StyledBox = styled(Box)((
  {
    theme
  }
) => ({
  [`& .${classes.root}`]: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },

  [`& .${classes.formControl}`]: {
    width: 150,
  },

  [`& .${classes.paper}`]: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },

  [`& .${classes.card}`]: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    backgroundColor: "#f2f8fc",
    textTransform: "capitalize",
  },

  [`& .${classes.textCapitalize}`]: {
    textTransform: "capitalize",
  },

  [`& .${classes.searchTextfield}`]: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.common.lightgreen,
      },

      "&:hover fieldset": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.common.lightgreen,
      },
    },
  }
}));
```

```
<Card
      color="primary"
      variant={ "outlined"}
    >
      <CardContent className={classes.card}>
        <Typography component="div" variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
               ID :
          <Box display="flex" gap={1}>
            <Box whiteSpace="nowrap" fontWeight="fontWeightBold">
              Name
            </Box>
            <Typography
              title={cardData.name}
              noWrap={true}
              variant="subtitle2"
              className={classes.textCapitalize}
            >
              {cardData.name ? cardData.name : "N/A"}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Typography
            title={cardData.uploadedName}
            variant="subtitle2"
            className={classes.textCapitalize}
            noWrap={true}
          >
            <strong>Uploaded Name : </strong>
            {cardData.uploadedName ? cardData.uploadedName : "N/A"}
          </Typography>
          <Box display="flex" gap={1}>
            <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold">Search Type : </Box>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">{cardData.search_type}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Typography>
 <TextField
          className={classes.searchTextfield}
          variant="outlined"
          type="text"
          label=""
          fullWidth
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
          size="small"
          placeholder="Search By Name, Search ID..."
          autoComplete="off"
          name="searchbar"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setQuery(e.target.value);
            setSelectData([]);
          }}
          value={query ? query : ""}
        />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
```

APP.js code

```
function App() {
  const theme = useCurrentTheme();
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppRoutes />
      </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Styles are not applied after the migration

Comment: this issue is fixed

Comment: set your component under whatever style name is set like example <StyledBox></StyledBox>

Comment: I have included component under style name.    <Root className={classes.appTitleWrapper}>
      <Typography
        variant="h5"
        align="center"
        classes={{ root: classes.sidebarTitle }}
      >
        <img src={logo} alt={''} className={classes.sidebarImg} />{' '}
        {title}
      </Typography>
    </Root>